# ES6- Template string getting wrapped up to single and not displaying in second line

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below code renders HTML content gets wrapped up but not in specified HTML format

Trying to display HTML content formatted as mentioned below inside contentediable div

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="htmltext"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#htmltext{
border:1px solid black;
  height:200px;
}
```

JS:

```
 let htmltxt =`
 <!DOCTYPE html>\n
 <title>Preview</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  // style
   <style>
     html { height: 100% }
     body {
       margin: 0;
       height: 100%;
      }
   </style>
   <body></body>`


    document.getElementById('htmltext').textContent  = htmltxt;
```

Trying to achieve output in below format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
 <title>Preview</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  // style
   <style>
     html { height: 100% }
     body {
       margin: 0;
       height: 100%;
      }
   </style>
   <body></body>
```

Comment: I'm confused what your issue is?

Comment: I am trying to add htmltxt content to contenteditable div and it is getting added in one line instead of multiple lines with format as mentioned

Comment: expected to be displayed (HTML code) inside div was mentoned at the last

Comment: You've mis-spelled `contenteditable` as `contentditable` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As you certainly already know, HTML ignores line breaks. If you want to display `pre`formatted, you’d have to use `pre`:

```
 <pre contenteditable="true" id="htmltext"></pre>
```

or escape your string, replaces line breaks with `<br>` and set the `innerHTML` property of `#htmltext`.